# Permanently route an host to VPN in OS X

Tags: macos, vpn

I need VPN from the university to ssh to my office computer. But each time I start the VPN, I have to route the host to ppp0 manually to use it,

```
sudo route add lab_computer.foo ppp0
```

because my previous attempt of rerouting was lost. And frankly it's a pain. I wonder if it's possible to use some script to automatically reroute it every time I successfully establish the vpn connection.

---

PS1. I am using OS X. But I think for both unix and linux system they should be similar?

PS2. I don't want to route all connection to vpn because in that way, the connection to other hosts will be unnecessarily slowed down.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put extra configuration in `/etc/ppp/ip-up` file, which is described in `man pppd`, and which is a standard shell script file that will be fired when the `pppd` establishes a connection.

I don't use the VPN anymore and unfortunately it seems I don't have a copy of my `ip-up` file anymore, but the way I used to do it is something similar to below (you'll need to verify this with the aforementioned man page).

Once pppd establishes the connection, it will call `/etc/ppp/ip-up` with the following arguments:

`ip-up interface-name tty-device speed local-IP-address remote-IP-address ipparam`

Your `ip-up` script could therefore look something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFNAME="${1}"
LOCALIP="${4}"
REMOTEIP="${5}"

if [[ "${REMOTEIP}" == "192.0.2.1" ]]; then
  /sbin/route add -host lab_computer.foo -interface "${IFNAME}"
fi
```

Please note the following:

1. I'm assuming that the IP address of the VPN gateway you connect to
   is always the same and never changes, and in the example above I'm
   assuming it's 192.0.2.1 ([RFC5737](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5737) address range specified to use
   as Documentation Examples - PLEASE CHANGE IT). The comparison here
   is used to only add the route when you're connected via the VPN to
   your office, and not any other VPN or PPP connection.
2. It's also better to use an IP address instead of the hostname for
   the computer you want to add a static route to. Instead of using
   `lab_computer.foo` I would use an IP address in the `route` command.
3. I'm using the `-interface ${IFNAME}` as opposed to hard-coding
   `ppp0`, which should make this work even if you have two VPN
   connections established at the same time (or a VPN and another form
   of PPP, e.g. a 3G modem)

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked. Though I have to chmod +x to `ip-up` to make it work. I also removed the condition shown in your example, as I have no idea what the value ${REMOTEIP} is for my VPN connection. (It's not the vpn route IP shown in GUI connector, nor is it the VPN server address.)

Comment: You can use `ifconfig` to know the corresponding IPs. The syntax is `LOCALIP --> REMOTEIP`.